# Django BigAuto User (how to get a 64 bit PK for the User table)

Tags: python, django

DJango 10 finally allow the BigAuto field to map to PostgreSQL's "bigserial" type --- which is fine, but the User table included by default still uses a regular 32 bit auto field as it's PK.

Now... don't get me wrong... I don't plan right now to have more than 32 bits of users, but I hate choosing a field that really might be too small.  And in my current case, it's reasonable to think that I will at some point have > 32 bit of users.

Anyways, regardless of motivation, how do I get a 64 bit PK on the User table so that I can still take advantage of django's built-in stuff?

Comment: 32-bit integers have a maximum size of 2,147,483,647. Are you *really* saying you're going to have more than 2 billion users?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser)

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.BigAutoField()
```

and in your settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```

Comment: I've been banging my head against this for about 24h.  Thanks for the answer, but in what I read now, isn't it easier to subclass AbstractUser?  I tried this, and the postgreSQL tables it creates appear to use id as primary key with bigserial.

Comment: Is this sorted out now?

Comment: I actually ended up using a combination of approaches and ... in-the-end copying a goodly part of the AbstractUser to use in my class the subclasses AbstractBaseUser and PermissionsMixin.  UTSL, I suppose.

Comment: Heh.  I was going to up-vote the answer originally, but I'd been told by the site that it didn't matter until I had a score of 15 or more.  Problem solved, tho.